# error with Warning: odbc_fetch_row(): 4 is not a valid ODBC result

Tags: php, ms-access, error-handling

I'm doing 2 queries

CALCULA_DEPARTAMENTO.PHP

```
$consulta=     "SELECT * FROM Dept INNER JOIN Userinfo 
        ON Userinfo.Deptid = Dept.Deptid
        where Dept.DeptName = '$departamento'";
```

with this one I select all the people form a department. then I do to make sure it works

```
$rs=odbc_exec($conn,$consulta); 
if (!$rs)
{exit("Connection Failed: " . $rs);}
```

and then to check all the results i do this:

```
    while (odbc_fetch_row($rs))
    { 
       session_start(); 
   ob_start();
   $_SESSION['departamento'] = $departamento;

       include_once("calcula_cono.php");
      calcularr();
    }
   odbc_close($conn);
```

in "the many things" y call another php which has this query to be able to look all the ins and outs of a person:

CALCULA_CONO.PHP

```
function calcularr()
 { 
     $departamento = $_SESSION['departamento'];

$consultaa = "SELECT  *  FROM Checkinout, Userinfo
         where Checkinout.Userid = '$userid'     AND 
             Userinfo.userid = '$userid' AND 
             Checkinout.Checktime BETWEEN   CDate('$fecha_inicio') AND 
             CDate('$fecha_fin')";

       $rss=odbc_exec($conn,$consultaa);
        if (!$rss)
        {exit("Connection Failed: " . $rss);}



        while (odbc_fetch_row($rss))
         { //more things here         
         }
  }
```

It finishes the first iteration and it does it well... but when he has to do the second one I get this error:

```
Warning: odbc_fetch_row(): 4 is not a valid ODBC result resource
```

Comment: Please post the code as-is (with irrelevant parts trimmed out) so we can follow the flow more easily. It looks to me like you are reusing `$rs` for two different `odbc_exec()` returns, inside your loop. In that case, you'll overwrite the outer one by the one in the loop and break everything.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the original code, but it may be that you just need to use a different variable than `$rs` inside the loop. I'll note that it's recommended to use [`odbc_prepare()`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-prepare.php) to create a proper parameterized query, rather than place your PHP variables into the SQL string.

Comment: i just changed the variable name as you guys suggested, is still giving me the same error. can post the whole code, because its over 450+ lines of code

Comment: You need to trim out the irrelevant parts from the code. What we need to see is how you are making ODBC calls inside your `while` loop.

Comment: please recheck, i have added some things to the code

Answer (score 0):

> It finishes the first iteration and it does it well... but when he has to do the second one i get this error:

That is an indication that some line of code inside your `while` loop is clobbering the result variable `$rss` (or possibly `$rs`, depending on which `odbc_fetch_row()` call is failing). Check your code carefully to ensure that you are not inadvertently assigning a value to the result variable inside the loop.